# How to access the HeaderAuthorization value from current HttpContext.Request.headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to pass a Authorization header to my REST API, I am setting my JWT Bearer token in Angular service using HttpHeaders. I could see the Bearer token in HeaderAuthorization property but how do I access it?

Below is the piece of code I wrote for retrieval:

```
var headers = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Bearer"];
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
Request.Headers.GetValues("Bearer").First()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var token = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Authentication.GetAuthenticateInfoAsync("Bearer")
```